# How to finding certain content with path and add one new Element?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

HI I have a php script which finds certain Words in an XML file. I would like to add a new XML element if a certain word was found at the end of the file. But in my code it add one every time it finds one.

What I am doing wrong?

XML:

```
<products>
 <product>
    <title>TestProduct</title>
    <Specifications>
      <item name="Specifications1">Test</item>
      <item name="Specifications2">Hello World</item>
    </Specifications>
    <body>
      <item name="Color">Black</item>
    </body>
 </product>
</products>
```

PHP:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('Test.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//*[contains(., 'Black')]") as $item) {
    $element = $dom->createElement('ID', '123');
    $item->appendChild($element);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

should look like that:

```
<products>
 <product>
    <title>TestProduct</title>
    <Specifications>
      <item name="Specifications1">Test</item>
      <item name="Specifications2">Hello World</item>
    </Specifications>
    <body>
      <item name="Color">Black</item>
    </body>
    <ID>123</ID>
 </product>
</products>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I undertood correctly, you can your change xpath  with

```
//product[contains(body/item, 'Black')]
```

Then the code will add new `ID` tag to the `product`, having `item` with the value 'Black'

[**demo**](https://eval.in/908474)

Comment: I edited it path to that so it should run through the whole product not only body tag? is that correct? `//product[contains(., 'Black')]`

Comment: Yes, if tht word can by anywhere in a product

Comment: glad to help. Good luck!